# Tomcat Error. ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a small tomcat 9 error. But I can't find it. Can someone make a small review of the following lines?

**This is: Error**

```
[Fri Jun 26 13:22:39.019 2020] [783:140640154666752] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1065): (local_worker_1) Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111)
[Fri Jun 26 13:22:39.019 2020] [783:140640154666752] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1725): (local_worker_1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Fri Jun 26 13:22:39.019 2020] [783:140640154666752] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2775): (local_worker_1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Fri Jun 26 13:22:39.019 2020] [783:140640154666752] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2796): (local_worker_1) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=3, client_errors=0).
[Fri Jun 26 13:22:39.019 2020] [783:140640154666752] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2991): Service error=-3 for worker=local_worker_1
```

**This is: mod_jd.log**

```
[Sat Jun 27 05:09:48.423 2020] [8540:139826577745664] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1065): (local_worker_1) Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:09:48.423 2020] [8540:139826577745664] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1725): (local_worker_1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:09:48.423 2020] [8540:139826577745664] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2775): (local_worker_1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Sat Jun 27 05:09:48.423 2020] [8540:139826577745664] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2796): (local_worker_1) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=4, client_errors=0).
[Sat Jun 27 05:09:48.423 2020] [8540:139826577745664] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2991): Service error=-3 for worker=local_worker_1
```

**This is: catalina.out**

```
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit] Failed to start component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit] org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1038)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:438)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The AJP Connector is configured with secretRequired="true" but the secret attribute is either null or "". This combination is not valid.
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProtocol.start(AbstractAjpProtocol.java:264)
[2020-06-27 05:12:40] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1035)
```

**This is: /etc/tomcat9/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="xxx" password="xxx" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**This is: /etc/tomcat9/server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
maxThreads="3000" minSpareThreads="50"
connectionTimeout="45000" />
```

**This is: /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties**

```
workers.tomcat_home=/usr/share/tomcat9
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ps=/
worker.list=local_worker_1,jkstatus
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=local_worker_1
worker.local_worker_1.port=8009
worker.local_worker_1.host=localhost
worker.local_worker_1.type=ajp13
worker.local_worker_1.lbfactor=1
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

**This is: Java version**

```
root@main:/var/log/apache2# cd /usr/lib/jvm/
root@main:/usr/lib/jvm# ll
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 46 root root 4.0K Jun 26 09:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Jun 26 09:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4.0K Jun 26 09:47 java-11-openjdk-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2.0K Apr 20 00:13 .java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Apr 20 00:13 java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-11-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 Dec 30  2018 default-java -> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

***Update***
After adding `secretRequired="false"` to server.xml the mod_jk.log was:

```
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:30.947 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (816): connect to ::1:8009 failed (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:30.947 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1065): (local_worker_1) Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:30.947 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1725): (local_worker_1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:30.947 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2775): (local_worker_1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:31.047 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (816): connect to ::1:8009 failed (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:31.047 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1065): (local_worker_1) Failed opening socket to (::1:8009) (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:31.047 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1725): (local_worker_1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:31.047 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2775): (local_worker_1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:31.047 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2796): (local_worker_1) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=10, client_errors=0).
[Sat Jun 27 05:31:31.047 2020] [8539:139826619709184] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2991): Service error=-3 for worker=local_worker_1
```

I changed server.xml and worker.properties port to 8007
**Ports:**

```
root@ub:/var/log/apache2# netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          13199      556/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          13201      556/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          68920      9527/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          68916      9527/apache2
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          11862      353/dhclient
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           0          12232      433/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                0          12233      433/chronyd
```

**Telnet**

```
root@ub:/var/log/apache2# telnet 127.0.0.1 8007
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**server.xml**
https://pastebin.com/YrEx1Qk6

Comment: errno=111 means there is no socket listening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `address` in the AJP connector.

```
<Connector port="8007" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
maxThreads="3000" minSpareThreads="50"
connectionTimeout="45000" address="IP-Address" />
```

worker.properties

```
worker.local_worker_1.host=127.0.0.1
worker.local_worker_1.port=8007
```

Comment: share latest mod_jk log snippet in question. Also are you able to `telnet Tomcat-IP AJP Port` from Apache machine?

Comment: Share your server.xml in question.Also run telnet tomcat-ip ajp-port command on apache machine and share result

Comment: Ok, I did everything as you said.

Comment: you are using the localhost . Is your Apache and Tomcat on the same machine?

Comment: updated answer. Please check and try. telnet showing port 8007 is not used by tomcat. So make sure that you are changing in proper file

Comment: Now I got a telnet connection. I updated it. It was because I commended in a commend in the server.xml

Comment: Now use same IP and port in worker.properties and test.

Comment: Oh, worked:D I think in this Debian based distribution the localhost isn't in the host file.

Comment: If you update this in your answer, you'll get the ✅

Comment: If you use 127.0.0.1 then localhost entry is not required. Even your 8007 is not listening that was your main issue.

Comment: worker.ajp13_sitename.host=localhost was breaking my routing, I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it worked thanks!